# Jstree creating new sibling for a node

Tags: jstree

I am in need of creating a sibling node for a node instead of creating a a child node using jstree. Is there any possibility for that.
Below is my context menu code for creating child node.

```
contextmenu : {
                    'items' : function(node) {
                        var tmp = $.jstree.defaults.contextmenu.items();
                        delete tmp.create.action;
                        tmp.create.label = "New";
                        tmp.create.submenu = {
                            "create_folder" : {
                                "separator_after"   : true,
                                "label"             : "Block",
                                "action"            : function (data) {
                                    var inst = $.jstree.reference(data.reference),
                                        obj = inst.get_node(data.reference);

                                    bootbox.prompt("Please Enter Block to add", function(result) {                
                                      if (result == '' || isNaN(result) == true ) {                                             
                                        custom_error('<i class="fa fa-warning"></i> Warning',"Please Enter Numbers");                              
                                      } else {
                                        var cfnum = parseInt(result);
                                        for(i=1;i<=cfnum;i++)
                                        {
                                            inst.create_node(obj, { type : "default",text:"Newnode"+i }, "last", function () {
                                                setTimeout(function () { inst.edit(); });
                                            });
                                        }
                                      }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        };

                        return tmp;
                    }
                }
```